# Python: How to read the elements of an array vertically and diagonally and see if they match the elements of a list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know if there is a way to check if in an array of characters, there are the words of a given list.

Here is my code for now:

```
import pprint

with open("C:/Users/luca/Desktop/Homework02/cp2_Animali.txt") as f:
    contents = f.read()

output1, output2, output3,output4 = contents.split('\n\n\n', 3)



with open('output2.txt', 'w') as o1:
    o1.write(output2)

with open('output3.txt', 'w') as o2:
    o2.write(output3)

read1= open('output2.txt', 'r')
read2= open('output3.txt', 'r')
l1e=[]
for line in read1:
    l1=list(line.replace('\n','').replace('\t',''))
    l1e.append(l1)
pprint.pprint(l1e)
l2e=[]
for line in read2:
    l2=str(line.replace('\n',''))
    l2e.append(l2)
pprint.pprint(l2e)
```

Untill now I have divided the text file in two parts in order to get a text containing the grid, then transformed into an array, and the other text containing the words i need to find in the grid, the words can be repeated and the same letters can be used for more words.

My text file is (including the spaces at the beginning and at the end, excluding the '):

```
'


Z   E   B   R   E   R   G   I   T   E
P   A   G   A   Z   Z   E   L   L   A
O   E   I   E   N   E   E   E   E   E
L   T   R   N   T   O   F   A   O   T
L   N   A   E   N   A   I   R   P   N
I   E   F   E   N   M   A   A   A   O
R   P   F   T   M   U   M   G   R   R
D   R   E   I   G   N   U   N   D   E
O   E   C   A   R   G   P   I   O   C
C   S   I   N   S   E   T   T   I   O
C   G   H   E   P   A   R   D   O   N
O   M   A   T   O   P   O   P   P   I
C   A   A   L   L   I   R   O   G   R


COCCODRILLO
ELEFANTE
GAZZELLA
GHEPARDO
GIAGUARO
GIRAFFE
GNU
GORILLA
IENE
INSETTI
IPPOPOTAMO
LEONE
LEOPARDO
PUMA
RAGNI
RINOCERONTE
SERPENTE
SCIMMIA
TIGRE
ZEBRE



'
```

Comment: Hilariously, I just solved this for [the exact same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53360018/2564301) – just to see if the algorithm in the answer works. (It does. Your answer is `PANTERA`.)

Comment: The close vote is mine, by the way. You do not show any attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If `output2` is your grid, let's assume it's unique, contiguous string instead of a grid. It's going to make the search easier, and let's assume that it has a length `n` and height `m`.

```
output2 = "mystringwithagrid...."
n = 5
m = 4
```

Then we can loop over all strings from `output3`, and check that can find the string in output2 with several patterns:

```
for string in output3:
    length = len(string)

    # search on each line
    for i in range(m):
        for j in range(n-length):
            if output2[i*n+j:i*n+j+length] == string:
                print("found horizontally at %d,%d" % (i, j))

    # search in diagonal
    for i in range(m-length):
        for j in range(n-length):
            if output2[i*n+j:i*n+j+length:n+1] == string:
                print("found in diagonal at %d,%d" % (i, j))
```

Add the other patterns that you want, and you have your result.